# How to add data dynamically in Dataset and legend in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, android-room, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm using ROOM database, in that database I've a table called **IncomeExpense**. And in that table I've two columns called **Category** and **Amount**. I get the data from table by GROUP BY Category.

`@Query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount,category from IncomeExpense GROUP BY category")
    LiveData<List<IECategoryModel>> getCategoryAmount();`

The above query return me the LiveData of amount and category. I want to show that amount in DataSet pie chart and the category in legend.

The color of pie chart and legend should be select dynamically also according to new entry.

```
private void addDataSet() {

    ArrayList<PieEntry> yEntrys = new ArrayList<>();
    yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(netIncome));
    yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(netExpense));

    //create the data set
    PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(yEntrys, "");
    pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(12);
    pieDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    //add colors to dataset
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    colors.add(Color.rgb(0, 100, 0));
    colors.add(Color.RED);

    pieDataSet.setColors(colors);

    Legend l = reportPieChart.getLegend();
    l.setEnabled(true);
    l.setCustom(colors, Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Income", "Expense"}));

    //create pie data object
    PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);
    pieData.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    reportPieChart.setData(pieData);
    reportPieChart.invalidate();
}
```

This is how I tried to show the Income Expense data in pie chart and it works perfect. But I don't know how to dynamically set the data of amount group by category in another chart.

please help me with this as I'm new in android.